# Is it possible to convert Blurays to my iPad?

Tags: video, ipad, encoding, blu-ray

Following on from my previous question, I was wondering if anyone could help me. I have a new iPad, so technically capable of displaying HD movies. And I own plenty of Bluray discs.

So I was wondering if it was possible to convert Blurays I own in order to watch them on it?

(Note: Let's set aside the legality discussion since a) laws vary based on jurisdiction and b) the Internet isn't a good place to get legal advice.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely!  You'll need a program to rip the Blu-Rays to your computer, then you'll need a program to convert them to a format that your iPad can understand (like [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr)).

[Lifehacker has a good guide that works with both Mac and PC for ripping Blu-Ray discs](http://lifehacker.com/5559007/the-hassle+free-guide-to-ripping-your-blu+ray-collection).